# jettyRun exploded war write issues on copy tasks

Tags: gradle, jetty, war

I've got a gradle project set up using jetty on an exploded war file in conjunction with the watch plugin. For any java dependencies, if the source is modified, the watch plugin will launch the 'jar' task and a copy task to put the resulting jar into the exploded war file. Using jetty's automatic reloading, this new jar is picked up. Everything works great.

I have a similar watch on a module containing javascript and css source files. Upon modification the files are built (concat/minify using the gulp plugin) and a copy task is executed to copy them into the war file. However, while attempting to copy the .js and .css files I get an exception caused by read-only issues since jetty is currently using the files.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue without having to stop/start jetty? Here are the relevant parts of my configurations / tasks.

jetty configuration is as follows:

```
jettyRun {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = project.name
    scanIntervalSeconds = 1
    reload = "automatic"
    webAppSourceDirectory = file(EXPLODED_DIR)
}
```

watch configuration:

```
watch {         
    clientwatch {
        files fileTree(CLIENT_SRC_DIR).include('**/*.js', '**/*.css')
        tasks ':client_module:assemble', 'copyClientFiles'
    }
}
```

copy task:

```
task copyClientFiles(type: Copy) {
    from fileTree(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR).include("*.min.js", "*.min.css")
    into EXPLODED_DIR
}
copyClientFiles.inputs.dir CLIENT_BUILD_DIR
copyClientFiles.outputs.dir EXPLODED_DIR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to my problem here:

```
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Files+locked+on+Windows
```

Which states:

> Jetty buffers static content for webapps such as html files, css files, images etc and uses memory mapped files to do this if the NIO connectors are being used. The problem is that on Windows, memory mapping a file causes the file to be locked...

To fix this I simply added the following under the `<web-app>` node in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```